# Read a text file into matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file containing multiple questions, and an answer (True / False) like this

1. A ball is squared. F
2. My computer is slow. T
   etc.

I want to make a function `[Q,A] = load.test(filename)` where

1. Q =  A cell array containing N strings.
2. A =  A logical vector of N elements.

I have tried different ways, but none seem to work.

```
[Q,A] = textread(filename,'%s %s');
This output here is the closest I've come:
     'A'
    'is'
    'F'
    'My'
    'is'
    'T'
```

what do I need to do ?

Comment: are there numbers in front of the question like here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have more than one `.` per sentence, the solution of Silas won't work. Also you loose the dot that way. You can also do it as follows:

```
fid = fopen('questions.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%s','delimiter','\n')
fclose(fid);

Q = cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-2), data{1}, 'uni',0);
A = cellfun(@(x) x(end),     data{1}, 'uni',0);
```

Alternatively use:

```
A = cellfun(@(x) x(end) == 'T',data{1});
```

to get the desired logical vector.

---

For a text file of content:

> The globe is a disk. F
>
> 42 is the answer to everything. T

you get

```
Q{1} =  The globe is a disk.
  
Q{2} =  42 is the answer to everything.

A =

     0
     1
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly how it should be, but what does 'uni' stands for ?

Comment: `...,'uni',0)` is the shortform of `...,'UniformOutput',false)` and tells cellfun to do the output in form of cell array. That is necessary, because all sentences have a different length and it is not possible to put out a char matrix. In the second case for `A` the output is either `0` or `1` and which can be arranged in a simple vector and `'UniformOutput',false` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) you should use `textscan` instead of `textread`

If you know that the strings are separated by a '.' or another specific delimiter you can do

```
parsed = textscan(file, '%s %s', 'delimiter', '.');
```